# Clipping in a widget's paintEvent

Tags: c++, qt, clipping, paintevent

I have a problem with clipping in Qt. I have a widget in which I paint a big  array of rectangles. As I only change a few rectangles from time-to-time, I want to paint only a little part of the widget (only these rectangles) and clip the paint area to these parts.

The `isNew()` function is true if the rectangle receives new color since the previous painting.

```
void Environment::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter painter (this);
    Tile t;

    //paint the matrix
    for(int i=0; i<size; ++
            t = matrix[i+j*yizeY];
            if(t.isNew()){
                painter.setClipRegion(QRegion(t.getRect()));
                painter.setBrush(t.getColor());
                painter.drawRect(t.getRect());
                t.used();
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? My program is running even slower when I use the `setClipRegion(...)` function.

Comment: but why you use `clipRegion`? What do you gain? IMO nothing! In this code you do not clip anything, you just enforce useless check of clipping what only cripples performance.

Comment: @Mark R. I understood `clipRegion` wrong. I thought it would prevent the program from painting everything new. Instead it just checks for the clipping region and doesn't allow changes there. You are right. That slowed the program down.

Comment: you are setting clipping region which is equal to drawn rectangle. In this code clipping only hearts performance, nothing is clipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to improve performance, you can paint all those rectangles on a QPixmap. As you can draw to the pixmap anytime, you can draw the tiles directly to the pixmap when they needs an update. On the paint event you just draw the "already-rendered" pixmap.

That way you don't have to remember which tiles changed, and you can avoid looping through the whole matrix.

Comment: Actually a quite obvious solution. It works perfect. I just pass the QPainter for the pixmap around and let every object paint directly. Thank you!